# Video Player in JS

Tags: javascript, video-player

i have followed some tutorials on YouTube (thenewboston) and i dont understand where is the mistake here. I followed exactly what it has been said(the HTML file and the CSS file are correct). I really don't get it:

```
function prima() {
    DimensioniBarra=600; // barSize
    MyVid=getElementById('MyVid');
    play=getElementById('play');
    barra=getElementById('barra');
    barraCaricamento=getElementById('barraCaricamento');

    play.addEventListener('click', PlayPause, false);
    barra.addEventListener('click', cliccaBarra, false);
}
function PlayPause(){
    if(!MyVid.paused && !MyVid.ended) {
        MyVid.pause();
        play.innerHTML='Play';
        window.clearInterval(AggiornaBarra);
    }
    else {
        MyVid.play();
        play.innerHTML='Pause';
        AggiornaBarra=setInterval(aggiorna, 200); // ogni 200 ms rikiama la funzione 'aggiorna'
    }
}
function aggiorna(){
    if(!MyVid.ended) {
        var dimensioni=parseInt(MyVid.currentTime*DimensioniBarra/MyVid.duration);
        barraCaricamento.style.width=dimensioni+'px';
    }
    else {
        barraCaricamento.style.width='0px';
        play.innerHTML='Play';
    }
}
function cliccaBarra(e){
    if(!MyVid.paused && !MyVid.ended) {
        var mouseX=e.pageX-bar.offsetLeft; // calcola la posizione X del mouse (vedi tutorial JS)
        var newtime = mouseX*MyVid.duration/DimensioniBarra;
        MyVid.currentTime=newtime;
        barraCaricamento.style.width=mouseX+'px';
    }
}

window.addEventListener('load', prima, false);
```

I have found the right code but i checked my file and im still not able to understand what did i do wrong!

Comment: You can't just use `getElementById`. You have to use `document.getElementById`

Comment: thank you XD. how did i not see that?